# How to retrieve value from javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm having trouble to retrieve the value from a javascript Object returned to me by a ajax call to a php webservice. I confirmed that the JSON returned is correct as you can see below:

```
{
    "json": [{
        "campeonato": {
            "id_campeonato": "630",
            "nome_campeonato": "Copa do Mundo\r",
            "nome_pais": "África\r"
        }
    }, {
        "campeonato": {
            "id_campeonato": "11",
            "nome_campeonato": "Série A\r",
            "nome_pais": "Brasil\r"
        }
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to get the object using **`response.json[i].value`** but whenever I try to alert this I get the message **undefined**.
And here is the funcition I'm using to the ajax call:

**webservice.js**

```
function listaCampeonatos(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/projetos/centraljogos/webservice/listagem.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {type:'listaCampeonatos'},
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response){
            //alert('Listagem bem sucedida!');
            //$('#resultado').html(JSON.stringify(response));

            //console.log(response);

            alert(JSON.stringify(response));

            for (i=0 ; i<response.json.length ; i++){
                //alert('Entrou no for / Pos. array: '+i);
                console.log(response.json[i].nome_campeonato);
                alert(response.json[i].nome_campeonato);
            }
        },
        error: function(err){
            alert('Ocorreu um erro ao se comunicar com o servidor! Por favor, entre em contato com o administrador ou tente novamente mais tarde.');
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Thaks in advance!

Comment: I see no `value` property in your json object. Try this: `response.json[i].campeonato.id_campeonato`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (i=0 ; i<response.json.length ; i++){
    //alert('Entrou no for / Pos. array: '+i);
    console.log(response.json[i].campeonato.nome_campeonato);
    alert(response.json[i].campeonato.nome_campeonato);
}
```

`json[i]` is this object:

```
{
    "campeonato": {
        "id_campeonato": "630",
        "nome_campeonato": "Copa do Mundo\r",
        "nome_pais": "África\r"
    }
}
```

So you have to access `campeonato` property before access it's properties like `id_capeonato`...

Working snippet:

```js
var response = {
    "json": [{
        "campeonato": {
            "id_campeonato": "630",
            "nome_campeonato": "Copa do Mundo\r",
            "nome_pais": "África\r"
        }
    }, {
        "campeonato": {
            "id_campeonato": "11",
            "nome_campeonato": "Série A\r",
            "nome_pais": "Brasil\r"
        }
    }]
};

// Directly
console.log(response.json[0].campeonato);

// Within a loop
for (var i = 0; i < response.json.length; i++) {
  console.log(response.json[i].campeonato);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought that the 'json[i]' would already enter the 'campeonato' object. How dummy am I? Thanks man!

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho it's ok, np. De br pra br (y)